# <select> <option disabled> makes option item disappear in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

```
<select class="form-control" id="service_select">    
     <option disabled="disabled"></option>
</select>
```

In chrome it is fine. Is there another way to make it disabled but not hidden ? Thanks.

Comment: Firefox shows the option: http://jsfiddle.net/Te6X7/

Comment: when adding another option, while opening the page firefox makes second(not disabled) option selected. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option isn't hidden - you just don't have any text in it:

```
<select class="form-control" id="service_select">    
     <option disabled="disabled">Place some text here</option>
</select>
```

If your first option is disabled (and therefore cannot be selected) Firefox will select the first non-disabled option.

```
<select class="form-control" id="service_select">    
     <option disabled="disabled">One</option>
     <option disabled="disabled">Two</option>
     <option>Three</option>
</select>
```

The first two options can be seen when you inspect the drop-down list, but cannot be selected - so "Three" would be selected in the above example.

If you want to prevent the user from selecting the first option, but want to display it - use the `required` attribute with an empty value...

```
    <select required>
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: yes! now, how to make it to select first option even it is disabled?

Comment: You can't select the first option - because it is disabled. Are you trying to create a first option like "Please select..." that you don't want the user to submit? There is a different technique for doing that.

Comment: what kind of technique?

Comment: I added it to my answer - use the `required` attribute with an empty value on the first option.

Comment: I have to check for value not to be empty in javascript, if user selects the first option. Ok, thanks for response. I wanted firefox to work like chrome. :(

Comment: The `required` attribute will check for you in modern browsers - no JavaScript needed.

Comment: Here is a working version - to get validation from the browser, you need to be wrapped in a form that will submit... http://jsfiddle.net/aD734/ - Tested in Firefox 25, Chrome 31, IE10 (the browsers I have to hand).

Comment: your select disappears after submitting

Comment: I'm posting to "about:blank" - in real life you would be posting to your server.